# Appending content to all posts in Wordpress. Appended content doesn't show in the archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a div to the end of each Wordpress post with a filter. The div will include a short description of each post that will only be visible on the blog archive.

With the following in functions.php, I was able to add the div perfectly to the post itself, but it doesn't show up in the blog archive. Is there a different hook that I should use that will show in both places (or even just show up in the archive and not the single post)?

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'insertPostContent');

function insertPostContent($content) {
       if(is_single()) {
          $content.= '<div id="archive_description" class="wpb_column grve-column grve-bookmark grve-column-1">';
          $content.= '<p style="margin:0;"><strong>Full Description:</strong>Lorem Ipsum</p>';
          $content.= '<a href="#">Read More</a>';
          $content.= '</div>';
       }
       return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is only targeting the template file `single.php` with `is_single()` you need to add `is_archive()` to target the `archive.php` template. Modify your function to.

```
function insertPostContent($content) {
       if( is_single() || is_archive ) {
          $content.= '<div id="archive_description" class="wpb_column grve-column grve-bookmark grve-column-1">';
          $content.= '<p style="margin:0;"><strong>Full Description:</strong>Lorem Ipsum</p>';
          $content.= '<a href="#">Read More</a>';
          $content.= '</div>';
       }
       return $content;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks that did it. I wasn't sure if `is_archive()` would just add that content to the bottom of the archive page, as opposed to each individual post. But it did what I wanted it to.